# How to login a user at backend without CSRF in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication, backend

I'm trying to make a user logged in at back-end who is already a user of another website of mine. For now I'm able to fetch the user's data from previous website's database using an API and make user registration during the login process. Same time I want this user to be logged in when data is just inserted because now user is existing. I tried to reuse same method `$this->processLogin();` but this method takes request `function processLogin(Request $request)` I can't feel passing email & pass to utilize this same method. I have tried guzzle self request with 3 parms  'email, password, _token' using POST request which didn't work. I don't want to exclude this route as well because it is being used for normal login. How can i make this user logged in right after inserting the required data? Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `\Auth::login($user)` and pass the user instance to it.

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI i think this worked, i just used `$userinfo = array("email" => $email, "password" => $password); auth()->guard('user')->attempt($userinfo);` Can accept as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
// if $id is your user that you want to login, then: 
auth()->loginUsingId($id);
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for your input, @BABAK ASHRAFI implied right that way.